# Flutter - Make a slide pannel looking like a Drawer

Tags: flutter, slider

I want to make a little panel sliding from the right `onPress` to display some information. I already have a `Drawer` in my `Scaffold` to display a menu.

I am looking for something like this :

[image]

I haven't found anything yet except for `Drawer`

Comment: I dont really get what you want to do . You have `Drawer` and you need to another one for displaying something else ? Would you explain it briefly please ?

Comment: Exactly. I already have a drawer for my navigation (sliding from left).
In some pages, I wan't to display another drawer (or something like this) coming from right when I press on a button for example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `drawer` and `endDrawer` property of the [Scaffold](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) widget. The `drawer` slides in from the start (left) and the `endDrawer` slides in from the end (right). This way you can have **two different** drawers, one on the **left** side, one on the **right** side.

Here a quick minimal example:

[image: Drawer Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: Center(child: Text('Left!')),
        ),
        endDrawer: Drawer(
          child: Center(child: Text('Right!')),
        ),
    ),);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're very responsive, Niklas ! :D
But I'm sorry, I'm not explaining myself well. I already have a drawer, but I want another one (or something like a drawer) in the same page. If I already have one, is it possible to make a second one in the same screen ?

Comment: This answer shows an example with two different drawers :D Do you want to use three or more?

Comment: Oooooooh oooooook nice it is exactly what I am looking for ! :O 
Sorry. It's morning, I'm tired.
Thank you Niklas, I won't forget to upvote for your answer when I have 15 points.

Comment: No problem! :) Thanks! :D